# needle in a stored procedure haystack

Tags: stored-procedures

I've been handed a stored procedure with almost 3,000 lines of code -_- for the most part it looks fairly benign, a lot of temp tables created, with end result of a data push via select statement from source into a target table. There are a few cursors within. Issue is when attempting to insert from source table (approx 40,000 rows) the SP runs, ends, but no data transfer. If developer just selects TOP 100 from source it runs beautifully and inserts data as expected. Without attaching all 2,650 lines of code can anyone give me tips on the who, why, and where this won't work for 40,000 rows but will work for 100 .. I am assuming possibly some sort of locking issue?? TIA

Comment: And which database system and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

### options

You have a couple options that make sense for figuring out where things are different, and one thing I'd check on outside of that.

### profiling

You could use extended events to set up a session that captures statement executions to see if row counts change along the way. Something like this may do it for you:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION 
    profiler
ON SERVER
ADD EVENT 
    sqlserver.sql_statement_completed
(
    SET
        collect_statement = (1)
    WHERE sqlserver.session_id = 138
)
ADD TARGET 
    package0.event_file
(
    SET filename = N'profiler'
)
WITH
(
    MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 5 SECONDS
);

ALTER EVENT SESSION 
    profiler 
ON SERVER 
    STATE = START;
```

Just replace the `session_id` (138) with the session id of the SSMS tab you're executing the procedure in its various forms, and watch the sessions as they run.

View the session:

[image: NUTS]

Add the rows column to the full output results:

[image: NUTS]

### printing

You could add print statements to the procedure at critical points after inserts to see if you end up with differing counts anywhere, and monitor the messages tab:

```
SELECT
    d.name
INTO #d
FROM sys.databases AS d;

PRINT ROWCOUNT_BIG();
```

### error handling

Sometimes errors are silently swallowed, like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT x = 1/0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH;
```

Instead of throwing a sane and rational divide by zero error, you just get an empty result set. I've run into this several times working with client procedures where the intent was to not return errors to the client for various reasons, but it made debugging issues quite difficult.